# Возврат на страницу с которой пришел в то место , где был клик

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Суть вопроса, как осуществить возврат на прошлую страницу , в то место, где был сделан клик?

Имеется галерея картин, при клике открывается страница картины, нужно что бы ссылка "вернуться", вела к тому блоку, на который был сделан клик.

Сейчас ссылка просто возвращает на прошлую страницу в самое начало.

Есть идея передавать каждому блоку позицию по оси Y в сессию, и при возврате назад смотреть или есть в сессии записи оси Y. Если да, то скролить туда.

Но желательно, что бы оно моментально возвращало туда, откуда пришел.

Например если нажать стрелку назад в панеле браузера , то возвращает туда, откуда пришел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте js функцию:

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
<script>
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: А разве хистори бек возвращает не в хедер ?

Comment: Он работает так же, как и кнопка "Назад" в браузере. И раз у Вас с ней всё хорошо, то и данная функция сработает на ура.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо я уже переработал. Работает и с хистори бек